# HTTPS authentication in Python 2.7

Tags: python, authentication, https

we are trying to pass the Virustotal API through our proxy which is getting denied. HTTP websites are accessible using the code but HTTPS is not going through. Request any of you to post few sample codes which would help us.

```
import postfile
host = "www.virustotal.com"
selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
fields = [("apikey", "-- YOUR API KEY --")]
file_to_send = open("test.txt", "rb").read()
files = [("file", "test.txt", file_to_send)]
json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
print json
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas to try

1) without HTTPS you can post to http://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan

2)  try the python requests library

```
import requests
params = {'apikey': '-YOUR API KEY HERE-'}
files = {'file': ('myfile.exe', open('myfile.exe', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan', files=files, params=params)
json_response = response.json()
```